# All matter will turn into Fe-56?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, time, quantum-tunneling

from what I understand, fe-56 is the most stable configuration of matter and therefore over time, so Dyson in "Time without end: Physics and biology in an open universe", thanks to quantum tunneling, the lighter elements will aggregate in Fe-56, just as the heavier ones will separate by fission.  Now, the question is, will it happen to all (absolutely all, in the sense that no other elements will remain, such as, for example, the wandering hydrogen proton sooner or later will aggregate with other iron) matter?

Comment: I have no idea how "thanks to quantum tunneling" hydrogen is supposed to turn into iron without proper fusion processes.

Comment: Check Time without end by Dyson

Comment: @ACuriousMind: “proper fusion” of the p-p chain  in the Sun core does happen “thanks to quantum tunneling”.